# compgen vs ls to list all files matching a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, glob, aix

I want a list of pdf files in a directory to use with a subsequent tar command. ***Important*** this list can be huge and I want to be sure I don't run into argument size limitations.

This is for an AIX system, hence the `-L` flag for tar.

```
if compgen -G "*.pdf" > ${filelist}; then
  tar -cf ${tarFilename} -L ${filelist}
  gzip "${tarFilename}"
fi
```

Is it better to use `compgen` as opposed to `ls`?

```
compgen -G "*.pdf"
ls *.pdf
```

Comment: `Is it better` what is used to measure "better-ness"? || It's best to use neither and just use the glob with the command you want to use it. `you want a list of pdf files`  `ls *.pdf` is better, because it's just 8 characters to type - `compgen` is way more and harder to remember.

Comment: [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: The right answer here really depends on what you're using the result for. Output of compgen is quoted as shell syntax; that's correct for autocompletion code (its intended purpose!), wrong for most other uses. Whereas `ls` is underspecified by POSIX, and only trustworthy for display for humans to read and no other purpose at all. For most programmatic uses `find` is the better tool (albeit not with the default `-print` action).

Comment: Your command looks great, I would leave it as it is. The `ls *.pdf` will be print error message if files are missing and will be slower then compgen. But don't you want `tar .... *.pdf`? I would also do one command `tar -f - | gzip > outfile`

Comment: @KamilCuk Doesn't tar ... *.pdf run into a size limit if there are a huge number of files?

Comment: Sure it does - which is great that you use `-L`. Seems like you got it all covered. Then only thing is that newlines in filenames will be a problem - well, unless you don't, cause who adds newlines in filenames anyway.

Comment: @Roland, ...do you have Python available? Its `tarfile` module is arguably a better choice.

Comment: BTW, consider `tar -c -L <(compgen -G "*.pdf") | gzip >"$tarFilename.gz"` -- no reason to create temporary files and run the code serially instead of in parallel.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately my AIX is so old that `tar -c -L <(compgen -G "*.pdf")` doesn't work :(

Comment: That should depend on the version of bash, vs the version of AIX as a whole -- on an operating system that doesn't support `/dev/fd`, versions of bash new enough to support that feature fall back to doing so with named pipes, and those are pretty much universal.

Comment: That said, consider `compgen -G "*.pdf" | tar -c -L - | gzip >"$tarFilename.gz"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My version of tar doesn't accept the `-` tar: 0511-192 Cannot open -.

Comment: `compgen -G "*.pdf" | tar -c -L /dev/stdin` :D ?

Comment: @KamilCuk `tar: 0511-192 Cannot open /dev/stdin.`
My AIX doesn't have it. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338667/unix-systems-without-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr

Comment: @KamilCuk is it possible to work some magic using `/dev/tty` or some other alternative?

Comment: Just `mkfifo tempfile; compgen -G "*.pdf" > tempfile & tar -c -L tempfile`.

Comment: @KamilCuk What is the advantage of using `mkfifo` as opposed to my solution with a conventional file?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433488/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-a-fifo-vs-a-temporary-file-or-a-pipe https://askubuntu.com/questions/449132/why-use-a-named-pipe-instead-of-a-file overall https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+the+advantage+of+using+mkfifo+as+opposed+to+my+solution+with+a+conventional+file%3F